# Default shipping country in Woocommerce Cart, not checkout

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, shipping-method

I have a WC shop that delivery to 2 countries in Europe. Issue I have is with unregistered users that don't have their data filled out yet.

I have countries A and B.
B is primary one, when user adds new item to cart he will see shipping for A, how can I set that if there is not data filled out to show shipping for B?

Order in my shipping tab is correct but for guests it always shows A as primary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to go to your woocommerce settings and in the general settings set your store default country (red box at the top) and the set the default customer location to shop base address or you may use geolocation to get default customer location. Try this in incognito window in your browser and you will see it works.

[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks, but this doesn't resolve my question. This is solution for checkout page. But in cart page this is not effected and doesn't work in proper way.

Comment: Thank you, this works. I forgot to mention that my country is different than selling 2 countries. Is there any solution for that ? So shop location is C, selling countries are A and B and B should be primary shipping. Sorry for bad question.

Comment: @Aljaz them put your store location to country which you prefer. Store location is not important to use. Otherwise you could change default customer location by geolocation. Then your problem should be solved. If it helped please mark my question as the right answer :)